# My methods aren't very DRY

Tags: javascript

I'm working through a series of JavaScript teasers to improve my general knowledge of the syntax, I've written a few array filtration methods so far, and I'm noticing that my code isn't terribly DRY. I'm not sure if it's because I'm used to Ruby's implicit return, and JS is just longer. How can I shorten these?

```
var selectElementsStartingWithA = function(array) {
  this.newArray = []
  array.forEach(function(n) {
    if (n.charAt(0) === "a") {
      this.newArray.push(n)
    };
  });
  return this.newArray;
}

var selectElementsStartingWithVowel = function(array) {
  this.newArray = []
  array.forEach(function(n) {
    if (n[0].match(/^[aeiou]$/)) {
      this.newArray.push(n);
    };
  });
  return this.newArray
}

var removeNullElements = function(array) {
  this.newArray = []
  array.filter(function(n) {
    if (n != undefined) {
      this.newArray.push(n)
    };
  });
  return this.newArray
}
```

Comment: This is a question more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanls @millerbr. I didn't know that site existed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's requesting a code review, rather than assistance with diagnosing a coding error.

Comment: Other than not being DRY there's no need for a temporary array when using `.filter` (and you could use filter in each of these three cases).

Comment: @nbrooks what off-topic reason did you choose?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you're basically reinventing the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. For example, in your first method, just rewrite it to be this. No need to create a new function.

```
var newArray = yourArray.filter(function(n){
  return n.charAt(0)==="a";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When using a method like filter, you should use it like this:

```
var removeNullElements = function(array) {
   return array.filter(function(n) {
     return n != undefined;
   });
}
```

Or maybe even better:

```
var removeNullElements = function(n) {
    return n != undefined
}

var nonNullArray = array.filter(removeNullElements)
```

The filter function is intended to return an array, and it will just keep all the elements that match the expression you return. Other methods you may want to look into are .map and .reduce

Last comment, I'd advise you to use !== instead of !=, but if you do want to check for falsy values you should also just be able to since undefined would be falsy

```
return n
```

Comment: Or ES6 `array.flter( n => n != undefined )` :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel:

```
var startingWithA = yourArray.filter((n) => n.charAt(0)==="a" )

var startingWithVowel = yourArray.filter((n) => n[0].match(/^[aeiou]$/) )

var withoutNullElements = yourArray.filter((n) => n !== undefined )
```

Comment: FYI you can get rid of `return` by wrapping the expression in `()` instead of `{}`, e.g. `var startingWithA = yourArray.filter(n => (n.charAt(0)==="a"))`

Comment: Hmmm. Arrow functions, not sure if I like them.

Comment: Why? I think the arrow functions make the code more readable.